# PHP - what do the curly brackets inside square brackets do?

Tags: php

I'm following a tutorial and this piece of code came up:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $inlen ; ++$i) { 

if (isset($this->morse[$in{$i}])) {
$out .= $this->morse[$in{$i}];
}

return $out;
}
```

`$in` is the key we're looking for in the `morse` array, but what does the `$i` in curly brackets represent in regards to the key=>value?

Thank you.

Comment: @cornelb it is array access, dont be confused!

Comment: What's different about this is not that it is inside square brackets. See the answer by @kingkero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, this is not part of a variable variable but rather String access (like `getCharAt()`). See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr) for more information.

```
$in{$i}
```

Becomes the character at `$i`th position of the string `$in`.

```
${'in'.$i}
```

Would be the variable variable `in$i` (`$in0`, `$in1`, ...)

---

This also makes sense as `$inlen` supposedly is `strlen($in)` and so the loop goes through each character of `$in`, one at a time.

Comment: **Note:**
PHP 5.5 added support for accessing characters within string literals using [] or {}.